# converting into Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query and i need to convert it into Linq query.

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.Students[0].StudentId = 1
and c.Students[0].StudentName = 'ABC'
```

Example schema for Students is

```
"Students": [
        {
            "StudentId ": 1,
            "StudentName ": "ABC",
         },
        {
          "StudentId ": 2,
          "StudentName ": "DEF"
        }
```

Please note that I am working in Cosmos and the above query is working correctly in CosmosDB Query window.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you try so far ? why using Students[0] in your query if you are trying to filter on studentId = 1 and studentName = 'ABC' ? 
What you are doing here with Students[0], is just filtering the first student.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var data=_context.Student.Where(std=>std.studentId==1 && std.studentName=="ABC").FirstOrDefault();
```

if you are using db context

_context is an object of db context

Comment: Unless something about LINQ-to-SQL makes this odd, you could also simply write `_context.Student.FirstOrDefault(std=>std.studentId==1 && studentName=="ABC")`.

Comment: Don't you both need `std.studentName`?